# Are min/max/normal groups only for the D-H parameters, with no relation to the RSA authentication/signing of the D-H parameters?

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssh, rsa, diffie-hellman

Using SSH (DH Group Exchange SHA256) with RSA authentication keys.

Since the initial handshake uses asymmetric algorithms (RSA, Diffie-Hellman) to handle authentication and setup of a shared secret, what is the relationship between these sshd settings:

- Max Group Size for Diffie-Hellman group key exchange
- Minimum group size for Diffie-Hellman group key exchange
- Normal Group size for Diffie-Hellman group key exchange

and

- the size of the RSA key?

For example, is the min/max/normal used to limit the acceptable key size ?

or are these completely different concepts?

**EDIT**
I do not believe this is the same question. Specifically speaking, this is ***not*** about **RSA key exchange** vs D-H key exchange and their key length relationship; as described in the linked question/answer.

Rather, this is in regard to RSA authentication option of SSH - used in conjunction with D-H. This is the RSA used to "sign" the D-H parameters going back and forth within the protocol. (It is also an alternative to SSH passwords).

Another way to phrase the question - are the min/max/normal groups specifically only for the DH parameters and have no relation to the RSA signing of the D-H parameters?

Comment: The concept is similar to how logjam works, there are several group sizes (1024, 2048...) 1024 is entirely known, using a key that belongs in this group is how logjam (after it downgrades) breaks the instance of a DH key exchange. The group size tells how many bits each key has in that group

Comment: @purefan: please see edit.

Comment: As far as I know group sizes are DH specific